# Simple Math in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm trying to multiply 2 specific values of a table in InDesign into another column. However, the table consists of numbers and text, which is all read dynamically from a csv file, and therefore subject to change.

I'd need the calculation to be updated accordingly each time the source changes, is there any script out there which might do that for me?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use csv for data-merging in Id. Then easycatalog plugin is for you.

OR

If you set a table in Id then just import excel file while in "preferences --> file handling --> create links when placing text files or spreadsheets" checked. Then your excel file would be visible in linked tabs like other files and you will be able to "reconnect" and update the data.